# How to post form data with ignoring the default value on a column in database

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want to create registration form but I need id_role to be static value for this form but the I couldn't insert data with this form because of that. I can do it manually from phpmyadmin with default value was already set but I cannot do that from codeigniter

I've tried to make it to be dropdown again and choose the id_role manually and it was working but I want to make every user who wants to register with this form has the same id_role value

This is the **role** table

```
CREATE TABLE `role` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `role` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

This is the **orang_tua** table. As you can see it has default value 3

```
CREATE TABLE `orang_tua` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `n_ibu` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `n_ayah` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `no_tlp` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `alamat` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `id_siswa` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `id_role` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 3,
    `pass` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `email_ot` (`email`),
    INDEX `FK_orang_tua_siswa` (`id_siswa`),
    INDEX `FK_orang_tua_role` (`id_role`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_orang_tua_role` FOREIGN KEY (`id_role`) REFERENCES `role` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_orang_tua_siswa` FOREIGN KEY (`id_siswa`) REFERENCES `siswa` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=12
;
```

This is the view for registration form and I want to make it automatic to choose 3 or if I can delete this role dropdown so every user don't need to choose anymore

```php
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="material-icons">people</i>
        </span>
        <div class="form-line">
            <select name="id_role" class="form-control ms">
                <option value="">-Login Sebagai-</option>
                <?php
                foreach ($all_role as $role) {
                    $selected = ($role['id'] == $this->input->post('id_role')) ? ' selected="selected"' : "";

                    echo '<option value="' . $role['id'] . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $role['role'] . '</option>';
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is controllers for registration form

```php
function daftarortu()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'Pass', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass1', 'Confirm Pass', 'required|trim|matches[pass]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('no_tlp', 'No Tlp', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('alamat', 'Alamat', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('n_ayah', 'N Ayah', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('n_ibu', 'N Ibu', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('id_role', 'Id Role', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('id_siswa', 'Id Siswa', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $params = array(
                'id_siswa' => $this->input->post('id_siswa'),
                'id_role' => $this->input->post('id_role'),
                'pass' => md5($this->input->post('pass')),
                'n_ibu' => $this->input->post('n_ibu'),
                'n_ayah' => $this->input->post('n_ayah'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'no_tlp' => $this->input->post('no_tlp'),
                'alamat' => $this->input->post('alamat'),
            );

            $orang_tua_id = $this->Register_model->reg_orang_tua($params);
            redirect('login');
        } else {
            $this->load->model('Siswa_model');
            $data['all_siswa'] = $this->Siswa_model->get_all_siswa();

            $this->load->model('Role_model');
            $data['all_role'] = $this->Role_model->get_all_role();

            $data['_regis'] = 'register/daftarortu';
            $this->load->view('layouts/reg', $data);
        }
    }
```

This is model for registration form

```php
function reg_orang_tua($params)
    {
        $this->db->insert('orang_tua', $params);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
```

I wanted to make automatic value which is 3 for this form for id_role column and so the role is consistent on 3 for new user who wants to register

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Remove select box with name "id_role".

Update your controller function as below.

function daftarortu()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'Pass', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass1', 'Confirm Pass', 'required|trim|matches[pass]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('no_tlp', 'No Tlp', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('alamat', 'Alamat', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('n_ayah', 'N Ayah', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('n_ibu', 'N Ibu', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('id_role', 'Id Role', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('id_siswa', 'Id Siswa', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $params = array(
                'id_siswa' => $this->input->post('id_siswa'),
                'id_role' => 3,
                'pass' => md5($this->input->post('pass')),
                'n_ibu' => $this->input->post('n_ibu'),
                'n_ayah' => $this->input->post('n_ayah'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'no_tlp' => $this->input->post('no_tlp'),
                'alamat' => $this->input->post('alamat'),
            );

            $orang_tua_id = $this->Register_model->reg_orang_tua($params);
            redirect('login');
        } else {
            $this->load->model('Siswa_model');
            $data['all_siswa'] = $this->Siswa_model->get_all_siswa();


            $this->load->model('Role_model');
            $data['all_role'] = $this->Role_model->get_all_role();

            $data['_regis'] = 'register/daftarortu';
            $this->load->view('layouts/reg', $data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It works but I have to delete `$this->form_validation->set_rules('id_role', 'Id Role', 'required');` first